# Creating a function without using print and input

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am creating a function useless with 3 parameters and the output is `'That was a waste of my time'`
The code that I tried is:

```
def useless("Hello, 95, "jello"):
   x = 'That was a waste of my time'
   return x
```

There is supposed to be an output but there is none... and it also says I am making a syntax error on the first line.

The output is supposed to be `'This was a waste of my time'`

I can't detect anything that is wrong... What can I do??
I am not getting an output and I am also having a syntax error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you missed the closing `"` in `useless` that would end at `Hello`. Python now thinks you want to include `"Hello, 95, "` and at `jello` it gets confused as hell, and so-on.

Also, you seem to have a fundamental misunderstanding of how functions use parameters and arguments. First, let's define the difference between the two. 
**Parameters** are what you put inside a function when you define it:

```
def Function(parameter_1,parameter_2):
    a = parameter_1
    b = parameter_2
```

**Arguments** meanwhile are the values you pass into the functions when you call them:

```
Function(argument_1,argument_2)
```

Thinking in mathematical terms, when you call a function where X=? and Y=?, you are saying:

```
"call Function, and plug in "value" for x and "value2" for y"
```

Running with these examples, you can rewrite your function `useless` in two ways:
You can do no arguments, where it will always return "x":

```
def useless():
    x='That was a waste of my time'
    return x
```

Or, you can pass arguments through parameters in the function to give more flexibility to your function:

```
def useless(x):
    return x

useless('That was a waste of my time')
```

Either will return the same line.

Finally, to ensure you know the difference between `return` and `print`; When using a function, you don't always want to print your result, but you still want to get it. That is where `return` works; Calling the function will then bring back whatever value that you tell it do with the `return` line.
For example, in the first `useless` I defined with no parameters, the function takes no argument and returns `x` as it is defined, always.
The other `useless` I defined, however, is essentially a "print" function because it takes the argument you give it and just returns it automatically.
Why `return` in these cases and not `print`? Because now that you're `return`ing, you have the option of telling Python to `print` *or* store `useless`! 
 Thanks to `return`, you can either write:

```
print useless(x)
```

*or*

```
variable = useless(x)
```

where now you can use `variable` however you like, even if you just do `print variable`.

I hope my over-explaining hasn't overwhelmed. If you still don't understand, try doing the [Codecademy Python tutorial](http://www.codecademy.com/courses/introduction-to-python-6WeG3/0/1?curriculum_id=4f89dab3d788890003000096), which may help you to conceptually grasp all of this (the website isn't completely behaving at the moment, but if you do the lesson in [Codecademy Labs](http://labs.codecademy.com), you can still hack your way through the tutorials).

Comment: Thank you! That helped alot. For Boolean though, If I were to use Boolean would I do : variable1 = True ? Is that how it works? (havnt learned Boolean yet....)

Comment: so it becomes for example: 
def useless(Hello, value, jello):
    (define parameters like Hello = ..., value = ..., jello = ...)
    x = 'That was a waste of time'
    return x

Comment: For booleans, you can either do True or False (or !True or !False, you see?)... But for your second comment, can you please reformat it with the `code` tag so I can understand it? :)

Comment: Also, if you thought my answer was best, please select it as your answer. When you do that, it awards me points for my effort. Likewise with anybody else! :)

Answer (score 2):

You are not getting any output *because* you have a syntax error.

Your function parameters are not valid; they are a) not valid Python like that, and b) incomplete:

```
def useless("Hello, 95, "jello"):
```

The `"Hello` string is missing a closing parenthesis, but you cannot just put literal values in a function header anyway. Remove everything between the parenthesis:

```
def useless():
    x = 'That was a waste of my time'
    return x
```

The rest of your function is fine:

```
>>> def useless():
...     x = 'That was a waste of my time'
...     return x
... 
>>> useless()
'That was a waste of my time'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def useless("Hello, 95, "jello"):
   x = 'That was a waste of my time'
   return x
```

should be...

```
def useless(Hello, value, jello):
   x = 'That was a waste of my time'
   return x
```

you can't have a string or int's as a variable name. You are declaring variables when you are setting args.

also just `def useless()` with no args is better in your scenario.